# Default To or Select first Item in Listbox using Jquery

Tags: jquery, json, asp.net-mvc, listbox

I am getting Json Response from controller and populating listbox using Jquery.

I want to default to or select item in Listbox. How can I do this ?

Here is my code.

```
 if (response.Assets.length > 0) {
      var list = [];
      for (var key in response.Assets) {
         list.push('<option value="' + response.Assets[key].Id + '">' + response.Assets[key].Name + '</option>');
        }
      $('#lstAssets').append(list.join(''));
  }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this,

```
$('#lstAssets :first-child').attr('selected',true);
```